# ApfloatMath.pow method returns almost the correct value

Tags: java, arbitrary-precision, apfloat

Here is a sample code:

```
ApfloatMath.pow(new Apfloat(25, 5), new Apfloat(0.5, 5));
```

The above code performs the square root of 25.
This returns `4.9999`.
I would've thought that this being arbitrary would return the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApfloatMath.html):

> `pow`
>
> Arbitrary power. Calculated using `log()` and `exp()`.

In other words, this does something like `exp(log(x) * y)`.  However, `log(25)` is irrational, and thus has an infinite number of digits.  Thus it has to be approximated at some point.

Comment: So there is no way to fix this?

Comment: @DanJoe: I'm not familiar with this specific library, so can't say for sure.  But this is just one example of how you shouldn't rely on floating-point calculations giving you "exact" results.  Even for arbitrary-precision types - as soon as an infinite expansion is required, results need to be truncated somewhere.